# WPF DataGrid работает ужасно медленно

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Моя таблица

```
                <DataGrid
                x:Name="dataGrid"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedData}"
                ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="DataGrid_ScrollChanged"
                Style="{DynamicResource MyDataGrid}" />
```

Я конвертирую Lua таблицы в Task<List>, затем хочу вывести их в таблице:

```
private async Task DisplayLuaTable(dynamic luaTable, DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    try
    {
        var dynamicList = await ConvertLuaTableToDynamicListAsync(luaTable);
        pagedDataViewModel = new PagedDataViewModel(dynamicList);

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            Binding binding = new Binding("DataTable") { Source = pagedDataViewModel };
            dataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding); dataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = true;

            dataGrid.DataContext = pagedDataViewModel;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error displaying Lua Table: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

**PagedDataViewModel** отвечает за ленивую загрузку данных:

```
public class PagedDataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int pageSize = 50;
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private List<dynamic> allData;
    private DataTable dataTable;

    public PagedDataViewModel(List<dynamic> allData)
    {
        this.allData = allData;
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        int startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        int endIndex = Math.Min(startIndex + pageSize, allData.Count);

        DataTable newDataTable = ConvertDynamicListToDataTable(allData.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));

        if (dataTable == null)
        {
            dataTable = newDataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable combinedDataTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                combinedDataTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                combinedDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in newDataTable.Rows)
            {
                combinedDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }
            dataTable = combinedDataTable;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataTable));
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        int startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        int endIndex = Math.Min(startIndex + pageSize, allData.Count);

        DataTable newDataTable = await Task.Run(() => ConvertDynamicListToDataTable(allData.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)));

        if (dataTable == null)
        {
            dataTable = newDataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable combinedDataTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                combinedDataTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                combinedDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in newDataTable.Rows)
            {
                combinedDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }

            dataTable = combinedDataTable;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataTable));
    }

    public async Task LoadNextPageAsync()
    {
        if (currentPage * pageSize < allData.Count)
        {
            currentPage++;
            await LoadDataAsync();
        }
    }

    public DataTable DataTable => dataTable;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        Debug.WriteLine($"Property {propertyName} changed.");
    }

    private DataTable ConvertDynamicListToDataTable(List<dynamic> dynamicList)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            if (dynamicList.Count > 0)
            {
                var firstObject = dynamicList[0] as IDictionary<string, object>;

                if (firstObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (var propertyName in firstObject.Keys)
                    {
                        // Добавьте проверку наличия колонки перед добавлением
                        if (!dataTable.Columns.Contains(propertyName))
                        {
                            dataTable.Columns.Add(propertyName, typeof(object));
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var dynamicObject in dynamicList)
                    {
                        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                        var currentObject = dynamicObject as IDictionary<string, object>;

                        foreach (var propertyName in currentObject.Keys)
                        {
                            if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(propertyName))
                            {
                                dataRow[propertyName] = currentObject[propertyName];
                            }
                        }

                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }
                }
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Он вызывается  при скорлле и подгружает данные в таблицу**

```
 private async void DataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.VerticalChange > 0 && e.VerticalOffset + e.ViewportHeight == e.ExtentHeight)
        {
            await pagedDataViewModel.LoadNextPageAsync();
        }
    }
```

само выполнение

```
await pagedDataViewModel.LoadNextPageAsync();
```

происходит довольно быстро, но при каждом его вызове UI начинает жутко зависать.
Сама таблица начинает зависать уже при 100-200 рядках.

Я пробовал отключать\включать виртуализацию, это ничего не меняет.

Очень надеюсь на помощь или совет в каком направлении искать проблему,

**Спасибо**

Comment: Чем более колонок, тем более нужно считать даже при виртуализации.

Comment: @vitidev, 15 колонок, 50-100 рядков, скролл на один рядок занимает 10-15 секунд, это разве большая таблица?

Comment: попробовал перенести таблицу в winform, она всю таблицу (5000 строк) отображает за пару секунд даже без ленивой загрузки